# Can't download additional tools for xcode 11.4

Tags: xcode

[image: Xcode fails]
I can't download additional tools for Xcode. Anyone else having the same issues?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out that I had to download it from Safari for it to finish the download.